# How can I make UILabel or UIButton with two lines , the first with one character and the second with two characters?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uilabel

I want a UILabel or UIButton  with two lines , the first with one character  and the second with two characters as the image below

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I made the circular shape but I don't know how to make the two line of text as in the image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiline `UIButton` just set `Line Break` to `Word Wrap` and set your buttons text with the new line character (in interface builder it is ctrl+enter).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myText = "3\npm"
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    myLabel.text = myText
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Why set numberOfLines to 0 and not 2?

Comment: Yes 2 is more specific. 0 means that it is determined by the number of `\n`.

Comment: setting numberOfLines to 0 means  multilines @Braains but 2 means 2 lines

Comment: You'll want it in, say, `viewDidLoad()` of a view controller or somewhere equally meaningful. I have edited the code to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have "3 pm" string,
 first split the string into an array

```
var str = "3 pm"
var strArr = split(str) {$0 == " "}
var str1: String = strArr[0]
var str2: String = strArr[1]
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.text = str1+"\n"+str2
```

But make sure that you have set the height of label properly to show the 2 lines.